# Strict Standards error, trying to reverse a string as array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a string with comma separated values:

```
$accounts = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
```

And I want to reverse that order. So I wrote this:

```
$accountsrev = implode(',',rsort(explode(',',$accounts)));
```

Basically I convert to an array, reverse the array, and implode it back into a string. What's wrong with that?

I get a load of errors like this:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/username/public_html/file.php on line 121
>
> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/username/public_html/file.php on line 121

---

## Edit:

Now I wonder if the way I build the $accounts variable is wrong. I pull 7 rows from the database and then build the $accounts variable in a while loop. The `id` is an integer in the database:

```
$accounts = '';
$i = 1;
while ($data = $getdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($i < 7) {
        $accounts .= $data['id'].',';
    } else {
        $accounts .= $data['id'];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Does the way I make the $accounts variable not produce a string?

Comment: If your first line really looks like what you are showing here, then you should fix that first: `$accounts = 1,2,3,4,5,6;` is not a string, `$accounts = "1,2,3,4,5,6";` now it is.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. I call 7 rows from the database and then build the string in the while loop. So my code does not actually contain that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just something that tells you you're doing something completely wrong:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];

rsort($array);

//$array is sorted.
```

However:

```
rsort(array_filter($array)); 

//Array filter returned a copy of the original array so $array is neither sorted nor filtered.
```

You need to do:

```
$accounts = '';
while ($data = $getdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $accounts .= $data['id'].',';
}
$accountsrev = explode(',',rtrim($accounts,","));
rsort($accountsrev);
$accountsrev  = implode(',',$accountsrev);//accountsrev is sorted here
```

Comment: +1 for providing not only a fixed version of the code but also an *explanation* of why OPs code didn't work.

Comment: The accounts variable was a typo and isn't really in my code. I create the string using a while loop with data from the database. Could you read the edited question?

Comment: @s1h4d0w I don't see why this would have been an issue but check my updated answer nevertheless

Comment: @apokryfos so the problem is literally that I can't combine the functions like `implode(',',rsort(explode(',',$accounts)));`? I still don't properly understand what is breaking it.

Comment: @s1h4d0w [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and all related functions require the parameters to be passed by reference (if you check the doc, that's that the `&` means). Only variables can be passed by reference (as the error says). `explode(',',$accounts)` is **not** a variable, it is a  function call. `$accounts` **is** a variable

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php   
 $accounts = '';
    $i = 0;
    while ($data = $getdata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $i++;
        if($i == 1){
             $accounts = $data['id'];
        } else {
           $accounts .= $data['id'].',';
        }
    }

        $accountsrev = explode(',',$accounts); // explode it as make array
        rsort($accountsrev); // then use rsort which sort array reverse 
        $accountsrev  = implode(',',$accountsrev); // again implode it 
        echo $accountsrev;
        ?>
```

then output will be

```
6,5,4,3,2,1
```

or you can use `array_reverse ()` function instead `rsort`

```
echo $accountsrev = implode(',',array_reverse(explode(',',$accounts)));
```

then output will be

```
6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Comment: The accounts variable was a typo and isn't really in my code. I create the string using a while loop with data from the database. Could you read the edited question?

Comment: Thanks for all the help! @apokryfos was just a bit quicker and explained that I can't use `rsort` like that.

Comment: No problem, I still very much appreciate you taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy:

```
$accounts = '1,2,3,4,5,6';

echo $accountsrev = implode(',',array_reverse(explode(',',$accounts)));
```